# .NET PostgreSQL provider based on libqp.dll

Tags: .net, postgresql

I'm looking for some database provider for PostgreSQL that is based on libpq.dll.
I alreade tried a [Npgsql](http://npgsql.projects.pgfoundry.org/) but it not use libpq.dll.
I made also a research but there is nothing I could google.
Do you know any ideas?

Or mybe the only solution is to write my own wrapper for libpq.dll?

Comment: Why? What problem are you trying to solve by using `libpq` rather than nPgSQL?

Comment: I have libpq.dll modified by my client and it's required to use only his specific library.
Until now I was using zeoslib in Delphi but now we are migrating to .net so I'm looking for solution.
Mybe I should write DLL in Delphi that wraps zeos and use it in my .net projects?

Comment: Wrap `libpq.dll` with P/Invoke I guess. Or enhance nPgSQL to do whatever your client's libpq does too